# How to convert normal XML template to AMP version?

Tags: blogger

Is it possible to convert blogspot XML template to amp version?  If yes then what is the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answers on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-implement-AMP-on-Blogger-platform).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. There are so many AMP-ready blogger template. You can download by free or buy license

Comment: it is better to give a link with example